# Телеграм-бот, большая часть эмоджи не работает

Tags: python, aiogram, emoji

Пытаюсь добавить эмоджи в свою клавиатуру, но большая их часть не работает. Значения для них беру прямо из телеграмма, сверял и с теми, что на сайте, одно и тоже.

Вот код клавиатуры

```
from aiogram.types import KeyboardButton, ReplyKeyboardMarkup
import emoji

menu_1 = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
    keyboard=[
        [
        KeyboardButton(text=emoji.emojize(':mag:') + 'Поиск')
        ],
        [
        KeyboardButton(text=emoji.emojize(':bar_chart:') + 'Курс')
        ],
        [
        KeyboardButton(text='Помощь')
        ],
    ],
    resize_keyboard=True
)
```

Вот как выглядит клавиатура
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте преобразовать эмодзи в юникод, есть вероятность, что телеграмм просто не воспринимает отправление эмодзи способом текста

Также предлагаю вашему вниманию библиотеку эмодзи (коды) -https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode

А также для более удобного преобразования символа бот **@getemojicodebot**, он вернет вам код символа